# Add C#-like extension methods for WebDriver using Java binding

Tags: c#, java, .net, selenium, webdriver

I wrote a lot of tests in C#, but now at new job i have to write tests in Java. I had a class that's adding extension methods to webdriver (in C#):

```
 public static class WebDriverExtensions
{
    public static IWebElement FindDynamicElement(this IWebDriver driver, By by, int seconds = 10)
    {
        WebDriverWait waiter = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds));
        IWebElement dynamicElement = waiter.Until<IWebElement>((d) => d.FindElement(by));
        return dynamicElement;
    }
}
```

When Im using webdriver it was something like that:

```
Driver.FindDynamicElement(By.XPath("//div[text()='Discount applied']"));
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[text()='Discount applied']"));
```

How can i make something similar in JAVA?

Comment: java doesn't support extension methods, nor lambda expressions. It's feature set is somewhat equivalent to C# 2.0 from 10 years ago, without properties and events.

Comment: I would create a wrapper around the `Driver` itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't do much besides creating your own static methods (that will have to "wrap" instead of using the "after dot" extension method syntax), or create a wrapper class for the driver and add your methods there.